# Rod passes through doorway: minimize height of doorway

Tags: calculus, optimization

I got stuck solving the following problem:

A rigid rod of length $l$ (blue line segment $\overline{MN}$) is trying to pass through a doorway $\overline{BC}$ into a tower of width $d < l$. One endpoint of the rod is always sliding on the floor. What is the minimal height $h$ of the doorway so that the rod can pass through?

[image]

The solution is supposed to be $h=(l^{\frac{2}{3}} - d^\frac{2}{3})^\frac{3}{2}$.

**My attempt:**

Let $x$ be the distance from $A$ to the endpoint $M$ of the rod on the floor. When $x \in [0, l]$ the rod has to be tilted upwards by an angle $\theta$ for the rod to be able to pass through.
**The part I'm especially unsure about is:** let's tilt the rod so that is touches the upper point of the doorway (as shown in the image). Then we can calculate $\theta$ because $x = l\cos\theta$ and from the triangle $\Delta MCB$ we have $h(x)=(x-d)\sin\theta = (x - d)\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{l^2}}$. Now we have to maximize $h(x)$ for $x \in [0, l]$. The derivative is:

$$h'(x) = \frac{l^2-(2x-d)x}{\sqrt{l^2-x^2}}$$

Setting this to $0$ gives $x = \frac{d \pm \sqrt{d^2 + 8 l^2}}{4}$, which when plugged back into $h(x)$ gives an ugly and incorrect expression.

Comment: Hint: check your result for $h(x)$ in the triangle $\bigtriangleup MCB$

Comment: Erratum:
$$
h(x)=(x-d)\color{red}{\tan\theta}
$$

Comment: Of course, that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0< \theta < \pi /2$ we must have $$l\leq NM=NC+ CM=d/\cos \theta +CM= d/\cos \theta +CB/\sin \theta =$$ $$=d/\cos \theta +h/\sin \theta,$$ So we must have $$h\geq l\sin \theta -d\tan \theta.$$ If $d\geq l$ then $(l\sin \theta-d\tan \theta)<0$ and there is no positive lower restriction on $h.$

If $d<l$ the maximum of $(l\sin \theta -d\tan \theta)$ occurs when $\cos^3 \theta=d/l.$

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you. Why did you state $NM \geq l$? $NM = l$ always holds.

Comment: If $l\geq h$ and if the rod has one end at  $M$ and the rod passes through $C$  then the other end of the rod lies somewhere on $CN. $..... When $\theta$ is sufficiently close to $\pi /2,$  the other end of the rod will not be at $N$.

Comment: Ok, that pretty much covers my question whether placing the other end of the rod to $N$ was justified.

Comment: You can now try to get a rectangle through the doorway, which can be also be solved with elementary methods. The analogous Q in 3 dimensions, of moving a box of dimensions $A\times B\times C$ may sill be an unsolved problem